# View v is unreachable statement

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

Please help me. 
Is this an error or a warning?
How can I solve this?
Error is that the `View v` is unreachable statement

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) { 
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent); 
    View v; 
    v = convertView; 
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    TextView champ = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView); 
    TextView year = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ImageView pic = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    champ.setText(adaptArray.get(position).getChamp()); year.setText(adaptArray.get(position).getYear()); pic.setImageResource(adaptArray.get(position).getSport());

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Your first `return` statement will entirely skip the rest of the method .

Comment: I would guess from the unformatted mess that you return before View v;

Comment: Remove this line `return super.getView(position, convertView, parent)` this statement make rest of the code to skip.

Comment: it is clear. your ` View v` is unreachable because before that line you used return : `return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);`

Comment: `return` on the first statement will cause the method to return value and end its scope. remove it and rest of your code, hopefully, shall compile and run.

Comment: The very first statement in your body is a **return** statement. That is all there is to this. So please go forward and *delete* this answer. I rather doubt that it could be helpful for any future reader.

Comment: seems you have started android without practicing java or any other OOP based language.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

Comment: would you please add some more details

Comment: Delete your first return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Anything else is written after the return keyword it's unreachable.
Remove return **super.getView(position, convertView, parent);**  from the first line of your function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning, telling you that static analysis of the code shows that some of your code will never be reached, because the method returns before.

The following is how you can resolve the issue and make proper use of the `convertView` by passing it to `super.getView(...)`:

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) { 

    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent); 
    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    }
    TextView champ = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView); 
    TextView year = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ImageView pic = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    champ.setText(adaptArray.get(position).getChamp()); 
    year.setText(adaptArray.get(position).getYear());    
    pic.setImageResource(adaptArray.get(position).getSport());

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this line of code at the *Top* of the method:
`return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);`

**When you `return` from a `method`, the rest of the code *inside* the `method` doesn't run.**